# How to create resx files

Tags: c#, resx

I am trying to use Icons in a windows form application. I read that you can use resx files to do this. (I also read that resx files can be used for localization but this is not the point of this question)

I know more or less how to *use* a resx file if I have one(see below). What I don't know and I can't find anywhere is how to create these resx files (I know what these files are already)

Can someone teach me how to create a resx file that holds information on icons **non-programmatically**  (the few responses about this in SO are programmatical ones)

The objective is to have a "resource.resx" file in my project that holds data about a "myicon.ico" file.

---

I am planning to use this as in

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("resource", 
                           typeof(Resource).Assembly);
Object ret= rm.GetObject("something");
if(ret!=null && ret is Icon)
  return (Icon)ret;
else
  return null;
```

Please don't point me to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/resources/creating-resource-files-for-desktop-apps) since I have already read it and could not find a practical way to do what I asked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you're using Visual Studio:

1. Right-click your project
2. Select Add | New Item
3. Select Resources File
4. Give it a name (e.g. `Resources`)
5. Click Add
6. You will now have a Resources file in your project with the name you provided, and it should auto-open the resources editor. If it doesn't, double-click it in the project.
7. In the top-left of the editor, click the "Strings v" drop down and select "Icons".
8. Drag your icon into this screen.
9. Rename it to whatever you want (e.g. `something`).

If you named your resources file "Resources", you should be able to access the icon like so:

```
Object ret = Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("something");
if (ret != null && ret is Icon)
    return (Icon)ret;
else
    return null;
```