# An analog for Qt resource files?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I need something similar to the resource system that Qt has.
Instead of writing the full path to the files and dragging them with the program, I would like to create a single file like Qt does and enter relative file paths.
I can't use Qt in my project, and using the. rc files that Visual Studio provides is very complex and cumbersome.

What can I use instead?

Comment: I'm pretty certain your assumption is wrong. Visual Studio does not require full paths in resource files. That would really break all kinds of source control systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need the .resx Resource Files.

A way to create this is to open Visual Studio:

> 1. Right-click your project
> 2. Select Add | New Item
> 3. Select Resources File
> 4. Give it a name (e.g. Resources)
> 5. Click Add
> 6. You will now have a Resources file in your project with the name you provided, and it should auto-open the resources editor. If it doesn't, double-click it in the project.
> 7. In the top-left of the editor, click the "Strings v" drop down and select "Icons".
> 8. Drag your icon into this screen.
> 9. Rename it to whatever you want (e.g. something).

If you familiar with the QT Resource files you will get to use it in no time.

Source: [How to create resx files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48637023/how-to-create-resx-files)

Brief doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/resources/creating-resource-files-for-desktop-apps

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/resources/working-with-resx-files-programmatically

Comment: @mrjbom2 I wonder If you want to use .resx file in unmanaged c++? If so, as far as I'm concerned, you couldn't. I suggest you could try to use .rc file.
For more details, I suggest you could refer to the links:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/how-to-create-a-resource-script-file?view=msvc-160
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/resource-files-visual-studio?view=msvc-160